# how to run lamp in env

Tags: django, wordpress, virtualenv

TL;DR

How do I encapsulate my Apache/PHP/MySQL/Wordpress installation in an environment or sandbox?

---

In my absence the designers-that-be have decreed that we use Wordpress for our newest project, as opposed to the Django-type applications I am familiar with. Another developer has already started making a custom theme, but now he's gone and I'm supposed to take over his work but I have no experience whatsoever with LAMP or Wordpress.

I thought it would be a good start to encapsulate the project into a proper standalone repository that I can copy and share between machines and people, put on github, etc, and most importantly: it needs to run in a virtual-env instance (or equivalent), so it doesn't mess up anybody's other projects, we can run multiple versions, etc.

Can anybody help me with that? At the moment it looks like the required files are spread out over my whole computer, I keep having to touch stuff in my root-directory, I need sudo simply to start and stop the *@#+ing server, it's complete lunacy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [virtPHP](http://virtphp.org/), [phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv) and [php-build](https://github.com/CHH/php-build) for creating isolated environments. As for typing `sudo` every time you need to start or stop the server, this is the right way of doing things.